# Upper back pain when I do dragon flag with bent knees

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, injury-prevention, back-pain, calisthenics, warm-up

I'd like to be able to do a dragon flag, so first I try to do it with bent knees. I can do this, but I feel a sharp pain in my upper back when I am about to raise my body from the floor. Once I am up, the pain subsides. It feels like it originates from my rhomboid muscles (I guess) like I am tearing them. What can I do to fix this? I know I could just quit, do something else, but I would really like to perform a dragon flag one day :)

Perhaps I should first do some kind of warmup? This is not my first exercise in the routine, I do pullups, squats, and overhead front raise before the dragon flag.

Is it normal to feel pain in this area?

Comment: What about progression exercises? Can you do leg raises without pain?

Comment: Oh yeah, no problem with leg raises.